# How to understand quoting variables deeply

Tags: bash

I test the following bash file test.sh. But how to explain the output. Sometimes I would remember quoting string variables means preserving whitespace in a single variable, but how to understand it instead of remembering it.

```
list="one two three"
for a in $list
do
    echo "$a"
done 

for a in "$list"
do
    echo "$a"
done
```

**output**:
one
two
three
one two three

Comment: Double-quoting prevents **word-splitting**. The default **Internal Field Separator (IFS)** is `$' \t\n'` (`space`, `tab`, `newline`) controls how unquoted strings are split by the shell. (which is called **word-splitting**). Meaning an unquoted string is split by the shell on any occurrence of a character in `IFS`. Double-quoting prevents ***word-splitting***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comment and explanation of *word-splitting* and the *Internal Field Separator*, here is a short example that should help:

```
#!/bin/bash

list="one two three"

printf "\nDefault IFS (space, tab, newline):\n\n"
for a in $list
do
    echo "$a"
done

for a in "$list"
do
    echo "$a"
done

printf "\nIFS breaking only on newline:\n\n"
IFS=$'\n'
for a in $list
do
    echo "$a"
done

for a in "$list"
do
    echo "$a"
done
```

(if you continue in a script and don't exit after setting `IFS` to a new value and need to restore the current (or default) `IFS`, either save the current (e.g. `curifs="$IFS"` and restore when done with your block, `IFS="$curifs"`) or just reset to the default (e.g. `IFS=$' \t\n'`). you can also, just run your block with the new `IFS` in a *subshell*, e.g. `(IFS=$',\n'; #do stuff)`, or in a `while` block, e.g. `while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do ...` )

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash ifs.sh
Default IFS (space, tab, newline):

one
two
three
one two three

IFS breaking only on newline:

one two three
one two three
```